# How can I make my self-hosted WCF service NOT try to reserve urls other than localhost?

Tags: c#, wcf

I would like to embed a REST API in a .NET 3.5 desktop app. On that framework version, there's only one option : self hosted WCF.

But I can't seem to make it listen on localhost only.

When starting, the app tries to make an url reservation for `http://+:8000`, which fails with a `System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException` because I'm not running it with admin rights.

I want it to only reserve `http://localhost:8000` and thus avoid the need for admin rights.

Using `HostNameComparisonMode.Exact` doesn't seem to change anything.

Here's what I've tried :

```cs
using Myservice;
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace consolehost1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Use exact hostname comparison mode
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact;

            WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service1), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/"));
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, "some-endpoint");

            //The host still tries to get a reservation for http://+:8000 and not just http://localhost:8000
            host.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Does the same happen if you use `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Answer (score -1):

Could the following command solve the problem?

- For Windows Vista, Windows7

> netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8000/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user

- For Windows XP, Server2003.

> httpcfg set urlacl /u {http://URL:Port/ | https://URL:Port/} /a ACL

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-http-and-https
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/http/add-urlacl
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option because calling netsh requires admin rights.

Comment: Http addresses are managed by a core driver called http.sys. 
When you want http.sys to make a request, you need to register the http namespace, which is an operation that requires privileges (administrator privileges).

Comment: True. But registering localhost (as opposed to "+") doesn't require admin privileges. And I only need localhost. I'd like WCF to understand that and not try to reserve "+". Like OWIN does with .NET 4+

Comment: It still prompts me that the requested operation requires permission elevation when I use the following command,
netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:1900/ user=Test
so I could not understand that registering localhost (as opposed to "+") doesn't require admin privileges.
Additionally, I don’t think there is a relationship with WCF, the communication based on the http protocol is managed by http.sys. would you mind sharing the similar issue that OWIN handles?

Comment: Wish the following link is useful to you.
https://serverfault.com/questions/822207/how-does-url-reservation-actually-work-in-windows-particularly-the-acls

Comment: The following OWIN self-hosting code sample runs on localhost without admin rights : https://github.com/aspnet/samples/tree/master/samples/aspnet/Katana/Embedded